# Создать связующую таблицу которая ссылается на одну таблицу

Tags: laravel

В Laravel можно создать таблицу пользователей и постов и связующую, далее можно узнать какие посты принадлежат пользователю.

А возможно ли имея одну модель к примеру **ObjectType** и таблицу к ней **object_types** с полями id и name и создать связующую таблицу

Я пробовал сделать что то такое но это не дало результата

```
 Schema::create('object_type_permissions', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('a_id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('b_id');

        $table->foreign('a_id')->references('id')->on('object_types');
        $table->foreign('b_id')->references('id')->on('object_types');
        $table->primary(['a_id','b_id']);
    });
```

Comment: А что должно дать результат? И зачем Вам это вообще, есл ито, что Вы делаете, обычно делается в той же таблице добавлением стобца, ссылающегося на себя?

Comment: У одного объекта должно быть несколько подобъектов в той же таблице.К примеру объект Дом и объект комната, вот в доме может быть комната и номер

Comment: Ну окей, а проблема то в чём? Ваша миграция должна работать. связи с модельню Вам нужно прописывать самостоятельно, чтобы что-то получить.

Comment: Вот в этом вопрос) Подскажите пожалуйста как я могу прописать отношения чтоб корректно получить данные?